# Wireless connection issue in Kernel 3.16

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, broadcom

I have upgraded my Dell Vostro 1720 laptop to 14.04.2, Kernel 3.16 (from 14.02, Kernel 3.13) but now I have no access to wireless networks.  My Broadcom driver PCI is 14e4:432b.  I've spent hours reading pages of various remedies to fix this issue & have looked through the synaptic manager, but I'm not sure what to remove/upgrade.  I have no experience in editing files so I don't want to make my problem worse.  I apologize if this is a duplicate question but how do I restore my wireless networks in the new kernel?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's the driver issue. With each new kernel release proprietary drivers would have to be updated by Broadcom, since they are closed source, open source community cannot tweak them. There may be solutions/ workarounds, but I'd suggest getting yourself another wireless card. I've been installing ubuntu for a friend and on her laptop she also has a Broadcom mini pci card. I just said, screw this, I'm gonna get another wireless card . Or downgrade to 3.13 kernel. Broadcoms are pain in the butt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bcmwl driver needs a patch to work with kernel 3.16 you need to get the Utopic version, just click the link for what Ubuntu version you have and then choose a mirror site to download from.  Then double click on the downloaded file
[64 bit version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download)
[32 bit version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/i386/bcmwl-kernel-source/download)

Comment: Thank you Jeremy31!  I was able to download the .deb file & install it in the Software Center.  I'm able to see all the network connections now.  I was getting cross-eyed with all the other answers requiring a lot of code editing.